# Async Await using VB.NET in manager class

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await

I am working on an application where I am facing an issue when I send a call to API it doesn't execute the after line and whenever I add a debugger on the API endpoint and spend a few seconds it works fine for me. The issue is with the async call I am sending using a manager class written in VB.NET. **GetBaseApiUrlAsync** The problem is with this method, and I fear my structure is not so good using async await.  Below is my Manager's class

```vb
Public Class HttpWebRequestManager

    Private Property mCurrMsg As MfgIntChargeItProSetupMessage = Nothing
    Private bearerToken As String
    Private baseApiUrl As String
    Private oID As String
    Public Property mUiContext As UIContext

    Public Sub New(mCurrentMsg As MfgIntChargeItProSetupMessage, mCurrContext As UIContext)
        mCurrMsg = mCurrentMsg
        mUiContext = mCurrContext
        Initialize()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Initialize()
        Dim locationSettings = (From d In mCurrMsg.Locations Select d Where d.LocationId = mUiContext.Context.DefaultLocationId).FirstOrDefault()
        If locationSettings IsNot Nothing Then
            oID = locationSettings.OID
            bearerToken = locationSettings.AuthToken
        Else
            Charter.UI.MessageBoxes.ShowInformation("Please setup OID and AuthToken for emerge pay to proceed.")
        End If

        baseApiUrl = Await GetBaseApiUrlAsync()
        Dim tt = String.Empty

    End Sub

    Private Async Function GetBaseApiUrlAsync() As Task(Of String)
        Dim baseApiUrl = mUiContext.Cache.GetEmergePayBaseAddress()

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseApiUrl) Then
            Dim posCallerService As POSCallerService = New POSCallerService(mUiContext.Context.ProductKey, mUiContext.Context.UserName)
            Dim config = Await posCallerService.GetPOSConfigurationsAsync()
            baseApiUrl = config.EmergePayBaseAddress
            mUiContext.Cache.SetEmergePayBaseAddress(baseApiUrl)
        End If

        Return baseApiUrl
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You are calling `Async Sub Initialize()` from the class constructor without awaiting it. So immediately after the `New` your class is not initialized yet. "A few seconds" after it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your Initialize method a function to return a task and then await it in the calling method. An Async Sub cannot be awaited.

```
Private Async Function Initialize() as Task


Public Async Sub New(mCurrentMsg As MfgIntChargeItProSetupMessage, mCurrContext As UIContext)
    mCurrMsg = mCurrentMsg
    mUiContext = mCurrContext
    Await Initialize()
End Sub
```